# AR Object tracking Android

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I am looking for an AR SDK on Android, that allows 3D object tracking with an OBJ-file or similar as the target reference.

We previously used Metaio for this, but since it was bought by Apple, we are searching for an alternative.

Vuforia is not an option, because it uses feature tracking for 3d object tracking and as opposed to edge based tracking.

Is there another AR SDK for Android that supportes edge based CAD tracking?

Comment: Did you try Wikitude? Since some months have passes, did you find an alternative to Metaio?